# Weak convergent sequences and norm convergent sequences in $L_{p}(\mu)$

Tags: banach-spaces

Let $1<p<\infty$. Let $(f_{n})_{n}$ be a sequence in the unit sphere $S_{L_{p}(\mu)}$ of $L_{p}(\mu)$ such that $(f_{n})_{n}$ weakly converges to $f\in S_{L_{p}(\mu)}$. Does $(f_{n})_{n}$ necessarily converge to $f$ in norm? It seems that it is true. But I am not sure. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, because if $f_n\to f$ weakly and, in addition, $\|f_n\|_p\to \|f\|_p$ then in fact $f_n\to f$ in norm.

Comment: Thanks, Teri. Could you give me a detailed proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $g_n=(f+f_n)/2$ and let $f^*$ be the supporting functional of $f$. Then $f^*(g_n)\to 1$, hence $||g_n||\to 1$. By the uniform convexity of $L_p$ for  $1<p<\infty$ this implies $||f-f_n||\to 0$.